# How to recursively copy a directory through gio

Tags: linux, smb, gnome3

I want to copy some directories off a remote SMB server. I tried to do it with `gio copy`, but it replies, that it cannot copy directiories recursively.

How can one make it so it will?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do true recursion with gio copy, but you can come close by doing

```
$ gio copy <directory>/* smb://server/sharename/path/to/existing/directory
```